# Controller is not getting loaded

Tags: angularjs

I have this state

```
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
    url : '/app',
    abstract : true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/leftmenu.html',
    controller: 'GlobalLeftMenuController'                
})
.state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'app': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/app-home/templates/home.html',
            controller: 'AppHomeController'                           
        }
    }
});
if(localStorage.userId === undefined || localStorage.userId === '') {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/signup');
} else {
  console.log("on otherwise going home");
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
}
```

Here

```
  console.log("on otherwise going home");
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

is getting executed but `AppHomeController` is not loading

Comment: did you tried `$state.go()` instead of `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like logic that should be added to `$stateChangeStart` which is a routing event listener that can be added to your main module's `.run()` block.

Furthermore, since you're using the UI-Router -- you should use `$state.go(name_of_state)` to redirect to a new route in your applicaton.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event, next, nextParams, current, currentParams)
    , function() {
         var userId = localStorage.userId;
         if(userId === undefined || userId === '' || userId === null) {
             $state.go('home');
         } else {
             $state.go('signup');
         }
    }
);
```